# Multiple resizable elements in a block with draggable borders

Tags: css, reactjs

I am currently working on a project in my React app and I need to make the below assignment:

[image]

The goal is to make a block containing of three parts:

1. full property
2. bare property
3. usufruct property

First we decide the full property (which is a percentage, and the remaining percentage will be split among bare and usufruct.

I want to be able to slide the blue lines horizontally (to set full property) and horizontally (for usufruct and bare property) and by that handling the resulting percentages of each category in React.

How can I best approach this? I tried using react-draggable, but it was an janky experience, so perhaps someone has a better suggestion to get me started?

Comment: I would properly solve it with the CSS `resize` attribute.

Comment: the problem with that is the the handler can only be in the right bottom corner, right?

Comment: resize attribute will help you build a CSS POC, but it will require Javascript to remove it to listen to mouse position . here is a CSS POC via grid , but indeed limited to the right bottom corner of the first cell via plain CSS. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JjaggbY